# Algorithm to loop over all item combinations, where some are deleted during the process?

Tags: algorithm, delphi, combinations

I am looking for a good algorithm/data structure to do the following:

Loop over all item combinations:

For example, for `A, B, C, D, E`:

```
AB, AC, AD, AE
BC, BD, BE
CD, CE
DE
```

(Symmetrical i.e., `AB` and `BA` are equivalent)

Computing the combinations is easy. However, during the loop some items are deleted, so if as a result of processing `AC` item `C` is removed, now the problem is to efficiently remove all other combinations involving `C` (that have not yet been processed), in this case `BC`, `CD`, and `CE`.

What is a good data structure/algorithm solution for this? Other than creating a matrix (which should be easy to work with, but would require in this case 5x5=25 instead of only 10 actual combinations).

Comment: Can you assume that only the last item is deleted?  That is while processing `AC` is it only `C` that gets deleted or might `A` be deleted instead?  In the case of `ABC` might you delete `B`?

Comment: Actually deleting makes it harder for both the algorithm and data structure. Marking an item as ignore then skipping output of any combination that includes it lets you continue using a regular list combinations algorithm. Can even use letters still by giving meaning to the letter's case, so A=use it, a=ignore it.

Comment: btilly: only 2 item combination (e.g. AB but not ABC); deleted item might be either (AC can delete A or C or none, but not both)

Comment: Brian: i can live with marking as ignore and performing the actual removal later, however the problem of efficiently earmarking the relevant items remains (ie BC, CD, CE will still need to be NOT performed, irrespective of what actually happens to C)

Comment: @hundreAd Could you specify your initial set and your result set?

Comment: USauter: not easily reduced to mre... basically you can think of comparing a list of files, and deleting those that are identical (this is an an example and NOT 100% representative)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

somewhat inspired by the comment from Brian, i'm considering the following implementation:

add an array `Deleted` corresponding to the items, i.e. `00000` for `ABCDE` (choosing Process rather than Deleted may have been more intuitive, but arrays are 0 by default, so this way saves looping over the array and initializing it to 1)

so after removing C the array is `00100`

the logic is to perform processing only if both items are not Deleted

this has the benefits of the actual removal of C not affecting any further processing and having a simple check on whether to perform processing

here is some code excerpt:

```
var
  Deleted: TArray<Boolean>;
```

```
      SetLength(Deleted, Count);
      // loop over TList
      for I := 0 to Count - 2 do
        for J := I + 1 to Count - 1 do
          if not Deleted[I] and not Deleted[J] then
            // process
            // if deleting I:   Deleted[I] := True;
            // if deleting J:   Deleted[J] := True;
            // (the above are mutually exclusive)
            ;
      for I := High(Deleted) downto Low(Deleted) do
        if Deleted[I] then begin
          // delete
        end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Judging from https://wiki.freepascal.org/for-in_loop you have the notion of an enumerator in Delphi, though I'm not sure how flexible it is.

I would recommend that the container has its elements in a doubly linked list.  This makes it easy to remove elements in the middle of the list.  It also keeps a list of elements that have been deleted with pointers to what the next thing was.  The subset enumerator keeps information including:

```
the size of current subsets
an array of the current subset
pointer to the last deleted element
```

getting the next subset is now a matter of:

```
if more elements got deleted and one of my elements was one of them
    find the earliest one in my list deleted
    advance along the pointers in the deletion list until I find myself in the values list
    construct the next subset to return
    return it
else
    if the last element can be advanced:
        advance that, and return it
    else:
        find how many elements at the end can't be advanced
        if only some:
            advance the first that can
            construct the next subset to return
            return it
        else:
            try to increase the size of the subset and start from scratch
```

The benefit of this approach is that if an element is deleted you stop even trying to construct subsets that contain it.

Answer (score 0):

I find it easier to think in code. The algorithm should be easy to extend to combinations of 3 or more elements and extension to more than 64 is a problem for someone else.

```
type
  sometype = integer;{for demo}

const
  first_element = 1;last_element = 5;
  flags : array [first_element..last_element] of int64 = (
          1 shl 0, 1 shl 1, 1 shl 2, 1 shl 3, 1 shl 4);
  human_interface : array [first_element..last_element] of char = (
          'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E');

var
  eliminate : int64;
  select1,select2 : integer;

  data_array  : array [first_element..last_element] of sometype;

procedure process(p_1,p_2 : integer);
begin
  writeln('processing ',human_interface[p_1],human_interface[p_2]);
  {Here we process the data in 'data array'}
  (* When we process AC, we decide to eliminate C*)
  if (human_interface[p_1]='A') and (human_interface[p_2]='C') then
    eliminate := eliminate xor flags[p_2];
end;

begin
  eliminate := -1;
  for select1 := first_element to pred(last_element) do
    if (flags[select1]) and eliminate = flags[select1] then
      for select2 := succ(select1) to last_element do
        if (flags[select1] + flags[select2]) and eliminate = flags[select1] + flags[Select2] then
          process(select1,select2);
  writeln('done');readln;
end.
```

So, each data element being processed has a bit identifier, bit 0 to bit 63 in `eliminate`, initialised to all-1-bits.

Then it's a sequence of nexted `for`s, starting at the successor to the previous value and ending at the (end-limit - depth). Add the significant flags together and if the result changes when ANDed with `eliminate`, then an eliminated element has been included, so we can skip the processing.

Possibly `eliminate := eliminate and not(flags[p_2]);` would be better in place of `eliminate := eliminate xor flags[p_2];`, just in case whatever the processing is doing attempts to eliminate the same element more than once.

Comment: while i appreciate the effort, that's a bit of an overkill, i only need combinations of 2

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the question about implementation with assumption "Chars".

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Classes, System.Generics.Collections;

type
  TItem  = record
  public
    constructor Create(AA, AB: AnsiChar);
  public
    A, B: AnsiChar;
  public
    function ToString:string;
    class operator In (A: TItem; const B: TSysCharSet): boolean;
    class operator Add (A: TItem; const B: TSysCharSet): TSysCharSet;
  end;
  TMyList=TList<TItem>; //Data to be processed

  constructor TItem.Create(AA, AB: AnsiChar);
  begin
    A := AA; B := AB;
  end;

  function TItem.ToString: string;
  begin
    Result := A + B;
  end;

  class operator TItem.In(A: TItem; const B: TSysCharSet): boolean;
  begin
    Result := [A.A, A.B] * B <> [];
  end;

  class operator TItem.Add(A: TItem; const B: TSysCharSet): TSysCharSet;  
  begin
    Result := B + [A.A, A.B];
  end;

  var
    i   : integer;
    It  : TItem;
    Lst : TMyList;
    MDel: TSysCharSet;
 begin
   try
     MDel := [];
     Lst  := TMyList.Create;
     try
       //Lst.add() ... Fill with data
       Lst.add(TItem.Create('B', 'E'));

       //Processing via a flat list
       i := 0;
       while i < Lst.Count do
       begin
         It := Lst[i];
         if It in MDel then
           Lst.Delete(i)
         else
         begin
           MDel := It + MDel;
           i := succ(i);
         end;
       end;

       //Test
       for It in Lst do
         writeln(It.ToString);
     finally
       Lst.free;
     end;
     readln(i);
   except
     on E: Exception do
       Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
   end;
 end.
```

If a TSysCharSet is not sufficient, you can switch to TBits.